# newbie help with jquery imagecube

Tags: jquery, 3d, cube, rotation

Hy I'm new here and new to everything that's related to webdesign and coding so maybe I have silly questions but that's it!,and also sorry for my english - hope you will understand what I have to say.

I work on this ImageCube http://keith-wood.name/imageCube.html but I would like to make it like this one http://www.cancan.ro/ with thumbscroller.

I know to make this things work only like this so if you know a better way to do it just tell me.

Whatever values do I put either in *html* or *javascript* can't seems to work like it should.
For example in the case from below all *thumbs*  get the first value from document in this case "0" which is uluru.jpg.So,in another words (in this case from below) whenever I click on whichever of the *thumbs*  the Cube repeatedly rotate the Uluru image.

So how can I assign the coresponding value to each thumb *img id* in order to function like a thumbscroller?

I also received this answer from the author

> You can use the *afterRotate* callback
>   to be notified when the cube rotates
>   and can then update the pointer in the
>   list of thumbnails. You can use the
>   *'rotate'* command to turn the cube on
>   demand for the previous/next buttons,
>   and for clicking on a thumbnail to
>   show that image. See the examples on
>   the Web site for sample code.

I can't seem to find how to use *afterRotate* callback and to update the pointer.

So if you can help me I would much appreciate it,and if you have other ideas please give me the entire code because like I said I'm very new to all in this field.

Here's my code

Code:

```
<div id="directionCube" class="cube">

            <img src="img/uluru.jpg" >
            <img src="img/islands.jpg" >
            <img src="img/gorge.jpg" >
        </div>




            <input id="direction" value="left" type="hidden"> <input id="current" option value='0' type="hidden" /> <img id="thumb1" src="1_thumb.jpg">

          <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#directionCube').imagecube({direction: 'up', repeat: true, pause: 3000, shading: true});

        $('#thumb1').click(function() {
            var cube = $('#directionCube');
            var current = parseInt($('#current') .val(), 10);
            cube.imagecube('change', {direction:$('#direction') .val()}).
                imagecube('rotate', current, function() {
                    $('#current').text($(cube.imagecube('next')).attr('title'));
                });
        });

        </script>


       <input id="direction" value="left" type="hidden"> <input id="current"  option value='1' type="hidden" ><img id="thumb2" src="2_thumb.jpg">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#directionCube').imagecube({direction: 'up', repeat: true, pause: 3000, shading: true});

        $('#thumb2').click(function() {
            var cube = $('#directionCube');
            var current = parseInt($('#current') .val(), 10);
            cube.imagecube('change', {direction:$('#direction') .val()}).
                imagecube('rotate', current, function() {
                    $('#current').text($(cube.imagecube('current')).attr('title'));
                });
        });     

        </script>


     <input id="direction" value="left" type="hidden"> <input id="current"  option value='2' type="hidden" ><img id="thumb3" src="3_thumb.jpg">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#directionCube').imagecube({direction: 'up', repeat: true, pause: 3000, shading: true});

        $('#thumb3').click(function() {
            var cube = $('#directionCube');
            var current = parseInt($('#current') .val(), 10);
            cube.imagecube('change', {direction:$('#direction') .val()}).
                imagecube('rotate', current, function() {
                    $('#current').text($(cube.imagecube('current')).attr('title'));
                });
        });     

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using interactive surfaces in [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/). You will ultimately have more control over anything 3D, unless you're scared of coding outside of jQuery. They have both canvas and webGL renderers.